# How to read a CipherInputStream correctly?

Tags: java, encryption, inputstream

I have a file encrypted with CipherOutputStream (using an AES key). Encryption works perfectly.
Now I would like to decrypt this file and save as another file. I'm using two streams to do it. Have a CipherInputStream initialized from a FileInputStream with appropriate key data, and a FileOutputStream initialized from a filename. I use this method to copy the file:

```
private static void copyStreams(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 10];
    int length;
    while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        os.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
}
```

The problem: `length` is always equals to buffer length (if file is larger than buffer). Therefore it never ends. It's an infinite loop.

I think the problem is in the way I detect the end of input stream.
How should I copy one stream to another correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That looks fine to me - are you sure it really *always* returns a large number? I'd expect it to go round as many times as it needs to, then halt. Can you post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Thank you very much.
I've found the problem. The problem was with ME, not with the above code. I was running it on a very slow filesystem (an older Android tablet), therefore it took suspiciously much time. For this reason I thought it runs infinitely.
Now I increased buffer size to 10MBytes, and it's now fast enough.
I don't know, should I ask the moderator to delete my question? Feeling myself stupid.

Comment: @ÁronNemmondommegavezetéknevem You can delete your own question because it has no answers. You become unable to delete your question if it (a) has more than one answer, or (b) has one answer with a positive score. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Answer (score 1):

The `read` method of an `InputStream` can return `0` indicating no bytes have been read although a next call to `read` may return more bytes. Your condition should reflect that.

```
while ((length = is.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
        os.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
```